# Imgur TOS change on May 15, 2023 may result in the loss of many media files in Arqade

Tags: discussion, images

Imgur announced new [Terms of Service](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-) that will go into effect on May 15, 2023, with one of the changes being:

> removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account

Related Meta SE post about this: [Imgur TOS change on May 15th 2023 could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stackexchange)

Note that the TOS change only applies to media uploaded at https://imgur.com/ (URL: `i.imgur.com`), not to images uploaded in an SE site (URL: `i.stack.imgur.com`).

This Imgur TOS change affects a large number of media files that are linked to or embedded in Arqade posts. The post authors either did not upload the media to SE Imgur, the media exceeded 2 MiB (the maximum size allowed by SE Imgur), or the media was in a format unsupported by SE Imgur, such as MP4, GIFV, or WEBP (SE Imgur only allows JPG, PNG, and GIF).

The good news is that *most* of these images have been successfully reuploaded to SE Imgur. This is thanks to Glorfindel’s efforts — you can read more details on their Meta SE post at: [Imgur TOS change on May 15th 2023 could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388726/162827) As of 2023-07-17, [posts all across SE have been edited to replace the non-SE Imgur URLs with the SE Imgur URLs reploaded by Glorfindel's script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391417/162827).

#### However some media could not be reuploaded to SE Imgur…

…because they exceeded SE Imgur's 2 MiB file size limit, were in unsupported formats, or have been deleted from Imgur. [In Arqade, there are 99 failed reuploads to SE Imgur](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md) (link leads to the results of Glorfindel's script). We could focus our efforts on editing those images, or looking for copies/alternatives if they've been deleted, to fit SE Imgur's requirements.

Comment: For large GIFs, is simply reuploading an option? The new TOS mentions "*removing **old**, unused, and inactive content*" (on the other hand, what constitutes "inactive"; I'm sure many of the Arqade pages are visited regularly..).

Comment: @Joachim Not if it's > 2 MiB. If it's ≤ 2 MiB, Glorfindel's script already has it covered. Yeah, that's the thing, we don't know what Imgur considers "inactive", to be safe, it's better to migrate them to SE Imgur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the failed reuploads at the time Glorfindel's script ran in Arqade (URLs and failure info are from the [results of Glorfindel’s script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md)). (Made Community wiki so anyone can edit.)

Note that this list excludes the media that have been successfully reuploaded by Glorfindel's script.

"Fixed" on the "Notes" column means that the media has been converted to be ≤ 2 MiB and/or converted to a compatible format with SE Imgur, replaced with an archive copy or alternative if deleted, and that the updated media has been reuploaded and edited into its associated post(s).

The "URL" column leads to the post(s) associated with the media file by linking to the [search results in Arqade of the following query format](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2Fexample.gif%22): `url:"https://i.imgur.com/example.gif"`.

---

Some notes on converting:

- For quick conversion, you can use [XnShell](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnshell/) (Windows only): it adds a few neat Shell Extension (right-click file menu) options.
- JPGs > 2 MiB can be made ≤ 2 MiB by saving them at a lower quality. Some image editing software, such as Irfanview, have a 'set file size' functionality. Setting it at 2048 KiB (= 2 MiB) should work.
- PNGs > 2 MiB can usually be made ≤ 2 MiB by saving them to JPG. Quality = 95 usually works.
- Imgur GIFV videos also have a GIF version in a similar URL pattern. E.g., https://i.imgur.com/example.gifv → https://i.imgur.com/example.gif
- GIFs > 2 MiB are a bit trickier to edit. Using a GIF optimizer such as [Gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) or [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/optimize), it may be possible to lessen its filesize to ≤ 2 MiB by doing one or more of the following: lossy GIF compression, resizing it to have lower resolution, color reduction to reduce colors to 128 or even 64, cutting its frames in half by removing every 2nd frame then slowing it down to 50% to get back to previous speed.
- Another alternative is to archive the post using services such as: [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) and [archive.today](https://archive.is/), so that the images in it can be edited back later. Note that this will only archive the image if it is embedded into the post. If it is linked but not embedded into the post you will need to archive the original Imgur URL, e.g., `https://i.imgur.com/example.gif`.

---

| URL | Failure | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uWGyyGA.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uWGyyGA.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/1UxRivS.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/1UxRivS.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/173215/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/1qeWOKe.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/1qeWOKe.gif%22) | JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] | [large file size - 38.7 MiB GIF](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/299561/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/2zx7X9o](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/2zx7X9o) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/3kgjmV8.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/3kgjmV8.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/454sD1R.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/454sD1R.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/4y4F9H7.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/4y4F9H7.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/5PN0Xib.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/5PN0Xib.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/62c1aGg.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/62c1aGg.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318396/222022) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/64nvqLx.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/64nvqLx.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/280033/222022) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/6LUS7Ik.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/6LUS7Ik.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/396340/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/6eSKe0y.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/6eSKe0y.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/7t6pCKz.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/7t6pCKz.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/8rd2q.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/8rd2q.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/42604/revisions) (replaced) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/92aaYAI](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/92aaYAI) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/98CMlvh.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/98CMlvh.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [no longer available](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235732/) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9fKKrtv.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9fKKrtv.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/358979/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9nHlTfv.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9nHlTfv.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9vvFrz4.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9vvFrz4.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/183546/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/9xM0jOh.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/9xM0jOh.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209310/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/BJHA7pF.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/BJHA7pF.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304203/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/BQtkflp.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/BQtkflp.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/277494/revisions) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/C2Vb7hs.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/C2Vb7hs.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/310276/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/D6J1P4I.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/D6J1P4I.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/248713/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/DtvRobI.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/DtvRobI.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/301993/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/EXrJifP.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/EXrJifP.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/173215/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/EkULFSp.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/EkULFSp.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/391579/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/FMjcDBt.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/FMjcDBt.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GmQdQxm.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GmQdQxm.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/294824/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GmZYsiX.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GmZYsiX.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/GrlkyNi.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/GrlkyNi.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201214/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/HEkvZmY.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/HEkvZmY.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/HRgupVM.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/HRgupVM.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/143074/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/JE7cP.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/JE7cP.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5467/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/L0F6k.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/L0F6k.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5476/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/MNNBo5l.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/MNNBo5l.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/297934/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/NI7zcse.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/NI7zcse.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316133/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/OQ5w7DN.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/OQ5w7DN.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/383879/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/OkX229e.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/OkX229e.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/On21DHS.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/On21DHS.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/379470/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/PiqW7.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/PiqW7.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5467/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/PuvvUPU.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/PuvvUPU.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/215242/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/QF86DfH.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/QF86DfH.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Qki1dyw.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Qki1dyw.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/336946/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/QsxScn1.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/QsxScn1.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/201836/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Rfnh2cu.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Rfnh2cu.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307743/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/T2B3xUM.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/T2B3xUM.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230906/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/TfXRbuI.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/TfXRbuI.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/337519/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/VyXmBQK.png?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/VyXmBQK.png?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/203764/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/Wm0FuXj.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/Wm0FuXj.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XIR5V9M.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XIR5V9M.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [no longer available](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235732/) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XbF4iYc.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XbF4iYc.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317382/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/XyLef0I.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/XyLef0I.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/399591/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/YDQYG0b.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/YDQYG0b.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385680/242480) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/YjzBjqF.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/YjzBjqF.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image; removed the image from the post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/249696/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ZeC7VQO.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ZeC7VQO.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/286809/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/aD7eICO.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/aD7eICO.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [GIF version is huge - 46 MiB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266347/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/aQJfAQN.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/aQJfAQN.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/358335/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/boPtDzn.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/boPtDzn.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/cvYGIMc.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/cvYGIMc.png%22) | APIException: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/d7FSfN3.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/d7FSfN3.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377720/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/dGwpTfn.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/dGwpTfn.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/dhApZMS.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/dhApZMS.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/diBLluQ.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/diBLluQ.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317302/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/e1zkciM.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/e1zkciM.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/286809/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/e8aFHXw.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/e8aFHXw.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/277494/revisions) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ekV1B2F.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ekV1B2F.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/280033/222022) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ezS0s2p.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ezS0s2p.gif%22) | JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] | [huge 32.3 MiB GIF; might need to be converted to multiple GIFs to maintain the quality](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/310789/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/f4olc2o.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/f4olc2o.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317382/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/fU1HGV1.webm"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/fU1HGV1.webm%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244027/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/fkDAP5h.jpg?1"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/fkDAP5h.jpg?1%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136470/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/gRd4wwp.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/gRd4wwp.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166555/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/h5toazj.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/h5toazj.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277099/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/hfewv2T.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/hfewv2T.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/245846/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/hj5yFCS.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/hj5yFCS.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230906/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/iTrJwYq.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/iTrJwYq.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/286809/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/j3JvvdB.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/j3JvvdB.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jGdNBfk.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jGdNBfk.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jRs4JAN.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jRs4JAN.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/213887/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jcIPYvq.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jcIPYvq.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/359698/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/jxGR4Ii.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/jxGR4Ii.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277095/222022) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/kaNzBeR.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/kaNzBeR.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/307763/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/kpHbPCH.mp4"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/kpHbPCH.mp4%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/386362/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/l4MUE4Z.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/l4MUE4Z.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/lQ7ReJe"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/lQ7ReJe%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/215714/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/mi2eDmA.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/mi2eDmA.jpg%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/nEgGMDp.jpg"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/nEgGMDp.jpg%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/307335/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/pf6zCZX.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/pf6zCZX.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/ruPmpaq.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/ruPmpaq.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/267102/revisions) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/scGMdg8.jpg?1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/scGMdg8.jpg?1) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136470/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uIBdHue.gif"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uIBdHue.gif%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/317382/7) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/uffL0kg.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/uffL0kg.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [no longer available](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235732/) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/v7xIlJX.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/v7xIlJX.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/380862/242480) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xGd89bn.gifv"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xGd89bn.gifv%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/360121/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xU2FUxk.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xU2FUxk.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304203/242480) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/xVNsn1F.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/xVNsn1F.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/294755/242480) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/y1fORtV.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/y1fORtV.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/260729/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/y3IpRf8.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/y3IpRf8.png%22) | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | [can't find an archive copy of the image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155571/4797) |
| [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:"https://i.imgur.com/z53TGQs.png"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22https://i.imgur.com/z53TGQs.png%22) | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | [fixed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/358335/4797) |

Comment: What do you think we should do in cases of completely broken images like the one in this post https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155571/163757 (which is the image that is second from last in this table)? Seems that some of them that have `FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached.` are broken images.

Comment: @TimmyJim I'd look for an archive of the post in archive.is or web.archive.org, and check if the image is there. If that doesn't work, I'd look for the archive of the image link itself. If there's no archive of the image anywhere, I don't think there's much we can do about it. If it's a GIFV video, I'd check if there's a GIF version. Archive.org doesn't seem to archive Imgur videos like GIFVs, but it might archive the GIF version.

Comment: There are a number of other instances like this, for instance https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235732/1351 (which also has deleted YouTube videos).  If it's on questions, it might be appropriate to close them as the necessary detail may no longer be there.

Comment: @Joachim and other volunteers: Should we remove the fixed images from the table instead of marking them as “fixed”? I'm thinking they don’t need to be there once they’re fixed.

Comment: @TimmyJim It has perhaps little to do with that particular warning: a few images with the exact same note were still present.

Comment: @galacticninja For now, leave them? I don't think it's a big obstacle currently, and it might give a better representation of the effort we put into this :)

Comment: Does anyone know why most of the images from [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230906/222022) were not picked up by Glorfindel's script?

Comment: @Joachim I've checked and [all the non-SE Imgur images in that post before Glorfindel's script originally ran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/8aae5891-fc7e-4139-8623-1a5e1df76535/view-source) were detected and listed at the [results of Glorfindel's script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md).

Comment: @Joachim Some are in the list above (Glorfindel's script failed to reupload them to SE Imgur), while some are not in the list because they have been successfully reuploaded by Glorfindel's script.